# Instantiate object classes inside a table cell in php?

Tags: php, html, oop, dom

I'm a bit new to a lot of things in PHP and HTML so please bear with me :)

So for my PHP project I'm developing a calendar program with a `Calendar` and `CalendarDay` class. To make the calendar display normally originally when I generated the calendars as tables they displayed everything aligned normally. I only used the `Calendar` class and each individual day/button was generated as a **DOM element.** Originally, the calendar looked like [this image here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvqhD.png)where all of the cells you can see are just HTML elements, which works fine.

But when I switched to OOP to try and generate each calendar day as an individual object, using the `CalendarDay` class, it doesn't generate as a table anymore and instead generates each day as a line break, shown in [this image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Kp7.png) (It's cropped but it generates all 31 days in the month like that vertically. It also has CSS style unlike the Calendar)

Is it possible to instantiate new PHP objects inside HTML tables if the objects outputs are DOMs, so that the objects are still aligned as a table?

The code:

```
class CalendarDay {
  public $dayNumber;
  public $dayOfWeek;
  public $daysArray = [];
  public function __construct($dayNumber){
    $this->dayNumber = $dayNumber;
    $daysArray[] = $dayNumber;
  }
  public function show(){

    $output = '<td>';
    $output .= '<div class = "Day"><span>' . $this->dayNumber;
    $output .= '</span></div>';
    $output .= '</td>';
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

**Arbitrary, just the set-up for the Calendar, not related to the problem**

```
class Calendar {
  public $month;
  public $year;
  public $days;
  public $week;
  public $dayOfWeek;
   //  Public as may be required for reminders
  public $weekdays;
  public $daysArray = [];

  public function __construct($month, $year, $weekdays = array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")){
    $this->month = $month;
    $this->year = $year;
    $this->weekdays = $weekdays;
    $this->num_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->month, $this->year);
    $this->date_info = getdate(strtotime('first day of', mktime(0,0,0,$this->month, 1 ,$this->year)));
    $this->dayOfWeek = $this->date_info['wday'];   // get the info including the day of the week that <given_date> falls on
    $this->previousDay = getdate(strtotime('first day of', mktime (0,0,0, $this->month-1, 1, $this->year)));
  }

public function show(){
    // The Calendar is a TABLE with each day as an individual table cell
    $output = '<table class = "Calendar">';
    // Print the current month and year at the top of the calendar
    $output .= '<caption class = "monthName">' . $this->date_info ['month'] . ', ' . $this->year . '</caption>';
    // New row to represent the days underneath the month header
    $output .= '<tr>';

    // Create days of the week header for each day in the array
    // For every day in the weekdays array, setting each of them AS a day ($day)
    // For each weekday in the calendar table print the day info (i.e. the date)
    foreach ( $this->weekdays as $days ){
      $output .= '<th class = "header">' . $days . '</th>';
    }
    // Separate each row of days
    $output .= '</tr><tr>';

    // IF the first day of a month doesnt fall on a sunday then use COLSPAN to fill the BEGINNING SPACE
    if ($this->dayOfWeek > 0){
      $output .= '<td colspan="' . $this->dayOfWeek . '"></td>';
    }
      // The num_days counter, starting from 1
      $current_day = 1;

      // While loop for building the whole calendar
      // While the current day is day number 0 to number of days in the month
      // Reset 'day of week' counter and clone each row if end of row
      // There are 7 days in a week.
      while ($current_day <= $this->num_days) {
        if ($this->dayOfWeek == 7){
          $this->dayOfWeek = 0;   // reset the day numbers for each row of 7 days, so that each row goes from 1, 2... 7 (Sunday to Saturday)
          $output .= '</tr><tr>';   // end that row of 7 days and start a new row
        }
        // Build each day cell (USE FOR LATER IN REMINDERS)
        // </td> tag ends a row of days once the day cells per line reaches 7 and creates a new one
```

Here is where the problem is as I attempt to generate new `CalendarDay` objects inside the `<td>` cells, but they do not align as if they are in a table.

```
        $output .= '<td class = "days">';
        $dayObject = new CalendarDay($current_day);
        $output .= $dayObject->show();
        $output .= '<button class = "calendarDayButton" onclick = "calendarbuttonform.php"><span>' . $current_day . '</span></button></td>';


        // Increment counters
        // Increase the day
        $current_day++;
        // Increase the day
        $this->dayOfWeek++;
        // Store the newly instantiated day in an array

        $daysArray[$current_day] = $dayObject;
      }
    //  Once num_days counter stops, if day of week counter is not 7, then fill the remaining space on the row uing COLSPAN
    if ($this->dayOfWeek != 7) {    // Resets at 7
      $remaining_days = 7 - $this->dayOfWeek;
      // Amount of remaining days in the week
      // span for the remaining days in the week
      $output .= '<td colspan="' . $remaining_days .'"></td>';   // span for the remaining days in the week
    }
    // Close final row once all of the days have been generated, in reference to "current_day++ 11 lines up"
    if ($current_day == $this->num_days){
      $output .= '</tr>';
      $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

Edit: Here is the code for instantiating

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  $test = new CalendarDay (date("d"));
  $test->show();
  $test2 = new Calendar (12, 2020);
  $test2->show();
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still reading over your Q, but I thought you might have some interest in [HEREDOC syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for strings. [Example w/ your CalendarDay](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f824f5368349f3fb74e5f85ba4fb02952049293b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I think, is with these two pieces of code:

#### The html output

```php
$output .= '<td class = "days">';
$dayObject = new CalendarDay($current_day);
$output .= $dayObject->show();
$output .= '<button class = "calendarDayButton" onclick = "calendarbuttonform.php"><span>' . $current_day . '</span></button></td>';
```

#### The CalendarDay->show() function

```php
public function show(){
    $output = '<td>';
    $output .= '<div class = "Day"><span>' . $this->dayNumber;
    $output .= '</span></div>';
    $output .= '</td>';
    echo $output;
}
```

#### The Problem

See this line of the html output

```php
$output .= $dayObject->show();
```

and this line of the `show()` method:

```php
echo $output;
```

`echo` prints directly to the output buffer (To be sent to the browser. But you're trying to append `show`'s result to a string. The simplest solution would be to change the `show` function to `return $output` instead of `echo $output`.

Since you're building the `$output` string & later printing it, but `show()` is `echo`ing immediately, your html isn't coming out in the right order. So you probably have a bunch of `<td>`s, then the `<table>` printing after it.

**EDIT**
If you **really** want your `show` method to `echo`, then you can use output buffering:

```php
$output .= '<td class = "days">';
$dayObject = new CalendarDay($current_day);
ob_start();
$dayObject->show();
$showResult = ob_get_clean();
$output .= $showResult;
$output .= '<button class = "calendarDayButton" onclick =
```

There are a lot of really great use cases for [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), but I don't think this is one of them. You could also add a function that returns the `output`, then just have `show()` call that method & echo the result. Then you'd be using the other function when building your `$output` string.

Comment: I added the the return keyword and it seems to work now, thanks I understand